How to determine whether a token's liquidity is locked or burned?
can someone tell me how to use the Solana/web3.js or Raydium SDK to determine if a token is burned or the liquidity is locked? What is the main idea? I've tried a few things, but none of them work
I have already looked at the answers on the solana.stackexchange website, but after testing, they are all inaccurate.

I didn't find a 100% working solution either, but this works in many cases:
https://github.com/degenfrends/solana-rugchecker/blob/main/src/checker/liquidity-checker.ts
Edit:
The code in the link is only working for AMM Pools, I am still struggling with CPMM and CLMM Pools. But at least I understand now why not all pools are working.

Have you solved it now, brother?

No, i didn't look into it yet again.
